# httplib.HTTPSConnection causes SSL errors in concurrent environments

Tags: python, ssl, httplib

I made a small python script to stress test a site I have been working on before it goes public. It operates by spawning a new thread every 5 mins that runs the below code in a while(true) loop.

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("site", 000, "pem", "pem", timeout = 30)
conn.request("GET", "/reports.php?" + url, headers = headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
read = (response.read())
```

If I have only 1 thread then the code request/response succeeds every time. As I create new threads I get the below error more often. Eventually when there are around 10 threads it fails around 90% of the time.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "stresstest.py", line 32, in threadproc
    stressTest(conn)
  File "stresstest.py", line 76, in stressTest
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1027, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 430, in readline
    data = recv(1)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 232, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 151, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: The read operation timed out
```

I was wondering if the ssl code httplib uses was not thread safe or if there was some other reason for the failings?

Answer (score 2):

It is thread safe. You might want to start looking into the performance of your server code...

Comment: Apparently the timeout will kill the connection after the specified amount of time even if a connection is successfully negotiated. I assumed it only timed out if it was unable make a connection in the set amount of time. After removing the timeout the all of the requests succeed, though still a bit slow than I would like.